# Error: Some conflicts were found on updating Android studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I am trying to update Android Studio 3.0.1 to 3.1 but after downloading and its starting patch but it shows error below. 
[image: Error while updating Android studio to 3.1]

Here is my **simple.xml.ftl** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
<#if hasAppBar && appBarLayoutName??>
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/${appBarLayoutName}"
</#if>
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}">

<#if isNewProject!false>
    <TextView
<#if includeCppSupport!false>
        android:id="@+id/sample_text"
</#if>
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</#if>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: someone downvote without reason. strange!

Comment: I had this problem today when trying to upgrade from 3.1 to 3.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today when trying to upgrade from 3.1 to 3.1.1.

After cancelling the patching (during first attempt), I started with a new upgrade (from Help --> Check for Updates). Second time, the upgrade was successful.

Comment: Not working for me. Same error.. can you post your simple.xml.ftl file? I want to cross verify

Comment: I don't have that file. What is the path ?